# MongoDB: findOne not working as expected?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm creating an API to my database of coins and I don't want to add duplicate coins to my database so I've created this line of code in my function

```
const addCoin = async (req, res) => {


const { coinId, seconds, bidAmount } = req.body;
  console.log(coinId);

  const coinExists = await Coin.findOne({ coinId });
  console.log(coinExists);
  if (coinExists) {
    res.status(400).send({ message: 'Coin Exists Bad Request' }); // bad request
    throw new Error('Coin already exists');
  }
```

In my Postman I am inputting a different coinId in the request body and I am getting the error that Coin Exists?
Is findOne here not working as expected?

Confused.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ahh after some documentation reading
I have to specify which property in the Coin Model I want it to find specifically
so in this case
I did

```
Coin.find({ itemId: coinId})
```

Since in my model its defined as itemId but user input is coinId

Comment: can you elaborate what that means?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).